# ¿Cómo hago que mi navbar se vea correctamente?

Tags: html, css, navbar, nav

estoy desarrollando una página web, estaba haciendo el navbar responsive pero me he dado
cuenta de que el botón que se pone para que, cuando está en tamaño de móvil, aparezca la barra de
búsqueda tiene solo 2 rayas, estamos acostumbrados a ver los botones con 3 rayas y este solo tiene dos,
y no tengo ni idea de como cambiarlo.

En la imagen se puede ver a la izquierda el menú que me refiero, me gustaría que se viese con sus 3 rayas, puede que sea una tontería pero es a lo que estamos acostumbrados y ver eso se me hace bastante raro.

[image: Est]

Aquí esta el código html

```
    <header>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <nav>
        <a href="home.html" class="brand">Brand</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-text="home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-text="products">Products</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{{ url_for('singup') }}" class="nav-link" data-text="sing up">Sing Up</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{{ url_for('login') }}" class="nav-link" data-text="sing in">Sing In</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Y este el css

```
*,
*::before,
*::after{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #eee;
    position: relative;
}

.overlay{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.85);
    position: fixed;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.menu{
    padding: 2rem 2.5rem;
    position: fixed;
    top: 1rem;
    right: 1rem;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 999;
    box-sizing: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.bar,
.bar::before,
.bar::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 3rem;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: mediumpurple;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    transition: all 650ms;
}
```

Gracias.